# What does the following form do in the code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= form_for [@blog,@blog.comments.build] do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.text_area :text, :size => '40x10' %> </p>
    <p><%= f.submit "Post Comment" %> </p>
<% end %>
```

This is handler by comments_controller, but I would like to know the reason, especially for form_for

Answer (score 0):

It adds a form with a text box, submit button and some hidden authentication related hidden fields for entering comment.
The comment is added to @blog object with relationship:

has_many :comments

Comment is build by the code if not present by:

@blog.comments.build

So overall you get a form for entering comments in a @ blog object. The blog object is necessary in this case and the comment will be automatically combined to the blog entry in proper column in comment record column "blog_id" by default.

This is called Nested Form Relationship, where instead of editing only one record of comment you can combine the parent object also and edit it.

build is basically used to create a structure for object, something like new ( e.g. Model.new). Form action is decided on the basis of given objects. In your case the objects are @blog and @blog.comments.build so the action called will be of either update of Blog controller or Create of Comments Controller..

Hope this helps.

Comment: does blog.comments.build and action? but the comments controller only has create action?

Comment: build is basically used to create a structure for object, something like new ( e.g. Model.new).

Answer (score 0):

The `form_for` creates a form for creation or update of passed object. If the object is not persisted, the associated url will target the creation action. Otherwise the targeted action will the update. `form_for` can receive many different kinds of parameter to generate the form.

If you check out the Rails `url_helpers` documentation, you will see that you can do something like:

```
<%= link_to 'First comment', blog_comment_path([@blog, @blog.comments.first]) %>
```

This will generate a link to the first comment of the blog with a path like `/posts/@post.id/comments/@post.comments.first.id`. This also assumes that you have the correct setup on your `routes.rb`:

```
resources :blogs do
    resources :comments
end
```

With this, you generate a bunch of paths that you can use to build, for instance, links and forms. Thus, the `form_for` in your code works similarly. Think of it as a url_helper. You have a `@blog` and a comment associated to the post(`@blog.comments.build`). As the comment is not persisted yet, the will generate a form for the creation of comments targetting `CommentsController#create`. The associated path will be something like `/blogs/@blog.id/comments` and the HTTP method will be POST.

Also, check these links to get more info:

[Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[Rails Form Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)